Somehow see the SQL query which Guidewire's Query API sends to server?
For debugging purposes, I want to see the SQL script which my Guidewire application sends to SQL server.
Is there some GW annotation, or some other way to tell Guidewire's framework to, for example, write those scripts to log, or to make it accessible to developer in some other way ?
I have tried to use SQL Profiler tool, but I do not have appropriate account on company's SQL server.
Also, the Query API code which produces SQL is not visible for me, since it is somewhere inside Guidewire's libs which I cannot access since I am working on customization, so I cannot use the debugger to try to see it.

You can use Profiler or create an extended events session. Either of those options will allow you to view all queries made against your server.

In fact I cannot. My account on my company's SQL server is not good enough for either of those options.

Well then you are out of luck, sorry. If you can't run an auditing tool on the sql server then you can't audit the queries. Maybe you can ask on the DBAs to run a trace for you?

I would concur with @SeanLange. If your company will not give you the tools to all queries made on SQL Server, then I would request higher privileges or enlist the help of a DBA.

Start a wireshark locally and see what queries are being sent to the sql server

That's one way.
The other way is to make ORM framework expose its generated SQL, and I believe it is feasible.

Could you provide more details around what query or functionality you’re looking to debug? The Guidewire profiler can capture SQL queries if you could wrap the entire function or lib call in a custom peofiler tag. Another way is to use some APM tools with SQL server connectors like AppDynamics. Although that would also need elevated privileges for you to install the machine agent on the server so getting the audit logs maybe an easier option as mentioned by others.

can you just debug your app until it reaches the queries and then see if there's some logging that can be enabled? I'm unfortunately a total noob with guidewire

Abhijay Kumar, I am debugging advanced claim search in Claim Center project. It does not return all claims we expect. I guess we have a data issue with some claim rows, and I want to see the details.

Note that I see people ask for this from time to time hoping to see the SQL statement after query parameters are substituted into the SQL command string. This is not possible, because parameter values are never substituted directly into the SQL command, even on the server. That's why we use them: in this way, any possibility of injection is completely prevented.

You can try to use the withLogSQL(true) operation before using the select on your query. You can then view the query in the log as it executes.
Sample : gw.api.database.Query.make(Claim).withLogSQL(true).select()
From GW:

Turns on or off SQL logging. The query is logged to the PLLoggerCategory.SERVER_DATABASE log category at the info level


I can not. My query api source code is inside Guidewire's framework and I cannot access it.

You can use the Guidewire Profiler to capture your session which will include all query execution within the profiler scope, including internally created queries.  Use of the profiler is documented in the product Administration Guide (requires login).  There is also training content for the profiler available on https://education.guidewire.com - just search for the keyword "profiler" to access that.
Capturing for a UI session is easy - press alt-shift-P, select the "Stack trace tracking" option and click the Start button which will drop you back to where you started.  Once your action of interest is complete, use alt-shift-P to return to the profiler screen and click the Stop button.  Profiling async operations is slightly more complex and is covered in the documentation and training resources already shared.
Analysis of the profiler information requires practice and education, again using the resources linked above.

you can set the Server.Database Logger to DEBUG level to see each and every database query that gets executed on the cluster.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
